# C# how to change a int number in the text file

Tags: c#, file

The text file format is this 
`11.11.15/8.00pm;Movie1;30`

i want to change the the last int number and save the text file when someone purchase the movie ticket.

This is how I print out the information on the text file

```
public static void nowShowing()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Date/time\tMovie\tSeats left");
            foreach (var seat in File.ReadLines(@"C:\test.txt").Skip(1).Select(x => new MovieSeat(x)))
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", seat.Date, seat.Name, seat.Number));         


        }
```

Comment: You want to change what's printed to the console? Or you want to change what's stored in the file?

Comment: i want to change what's stored in the file.

Comment: you should use a parser for the semi-colon separate values file.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below will give you the ability to decrement your availability.

```
internal class MovieEntryParser
{
    internal static string DecrementAvailability( string input )
    {
        string[] details = input.Split( ';' );

        // relevant error checking

        int availability = int.Parse( details[ 2 ] ); // use try parse

        availability--;

        return string.Format( "{0};{1};{2}", details[ 0 ], details[ 1 ], availability );
    }
}
```

Comment: And then the OP will need code to write it back out to the file, which should probably be a separate question.